# pandas.to_datetime -> ValueError: unconverted data remains: 01

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert the str column below:

```
data['date']

0          Apr-2001
1          Jun-1987
2          Apr-2011
3          Feb-2006
4          Dec-2000
             ...   
2260663    Jan-2004
2260664    Mar-2003
2260665    Feb-1995
2260666    Jul-2003
2260667    Apr-2014
Name: earliest_cr_line, Length: 2260668, dtype: object
```

to a datatime column :

```
data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], format = '%b-%y')
```

which gives me the following error msg

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 01
```

Could someone please advise what is wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: check out [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) - %y is for 2-digit year, %Y is for 4-digit year. Voting to close because of typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Y` for years in format `YYYY`:

```
data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], format = '%b-%Y')
```

Like @MrFuppes mentioned, also working:

```
data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
```

If need format without days is possible use monthly periods:

```
data['per'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date']).dt.to_period('m')
```

Comment: just pd.to_datetime should do, no? (format not needed)

Comment: works both ways thanks,  btw it gives this format : 2001-04-01 is it possible without days?

Comment: @SkittlesBrah - No, if need datetimes need also `days`, if need remove it close is month periods, added to answer.